# Testing a Series for Convergence or Divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

The problem is to test the following series for convergence:

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} ((i^2+1)/(i^3+1))$

I tried several tests like the root and limit comparison test but they yielded no usable results. I found online that this series would diverge by the comparison test, however, I am not sure what series I would compare this to. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I found limit comparison quite useful here.

Comment: The summands in your series act *very similarly* to $\frac{1}{i}$.  You should know the series whose summands are $\frac{1}{i}$ is the harmonic series which diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is divergent as one can compare with the divergent series $\sum \dfrac{1}{i} $:

$$ \dfrac{1+i^2 }{1+i^3} > \frac{i^2}{i^3 + i^3} = \frac{1}{2i} $$

Comment: I would get to a similar point in my work, however, the sum in the original problem would be less than that divergent sum. Wouldn't that be inconclusive by the comparison test?

Comment: It is greater. Recall that if $\sum a_n$ diverges, then $\sum k a_n$ diverges

Comment: Thank you for the clarification in the work. My professor had not introduced to us the idea of comparing it to another function/series that differed in terms of the variable "i", only by constants so I hadn't thought of this approach. This makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the *limit comparison test* with the sequence $a_i = \frac{1}{i}$.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way uses an asymptotic equivalent:

We know that a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its  leading, and the equivalence of functions is compatible with multiplication and division, so
$i^2+1\sim_\infty i^2$, $i^3+1\sim_\infty i^3$, whence
$$\frac{i^2+1}{i^3+1}\sim_\infty\frac{i^2}{i^3}=\frac1 i,$$
and the latter series diverges, therefore the given series diverges too.